# Qt App crashes on loading qml in retail mode if the QML was pre-compiled in Qt 5.8 and above

Tags: qt, qml, precompile

I have Qt App that uses QQuickView which loads qml using qrc: path because the qml is pre-compiled. This used to work fine until Qt 5.7 But with Qt 5.8 and Qt 5.9, the application crashes in retail mode. If I try to load qml run-time directly by giving it the absolute path instead of qrc: path it works fine. In debug mode, both pre-compile and non pre-compile version works well. I am not sure what changed in Qt 5.8 that is causing this. The crashing is originating in QtQml.dll in a function that seems to load qml. Anybody else hit similar issue or know what might be wrong?

Comment: You could show your code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't post my production code. I was trying to write a sample Qt Quick App to repro and while doing so, I figured out the issue. Adding QT_NO_DEBUG compiler flag while compiling .cpp that was converted from .qml/.js using qtquickcompiler was causing the crash. This was only happening if I used qtquick compiler to compile qml/js and use the build flag QT_NO_DEBUG.